# downloading excelize xlsx file is corrupt

Tags: go, webserver, xlsx

I'm using [Excelize](http://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) library for generating xlsx documents. When I use It's `Write(io.writer)` func for saving xlsx to file, it works perfectly. But I need to generate and serve this file at web-server. I was trying this solution

```
func GetConsolidatedReport(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var reportFile *excelize.File

    ...

    var b bytes.Buffer
    writr := bufio.NewWriter(&b)
    reportFile.SaveAs("/tmp/testfile.xlsx")
    reportFile.Write(writr)
    writr.Flush()

    fileContents := b.Bytes()
    fileSize := strconv.Itoa(len(fileContents))

    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xlsx")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", fileSize)

    t := bytes.NewReader(b.Bytes())
    io.Copy(w, t)
}
```

and after that i've got corrupted zip-file from web-server, but normal file saved in "/tmp/testfile.xlsx"

I've tried content-type as `application/zip`, `application/octet-stream`, `application/vnd.*` but no luck.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

PS: By serving i mean on-the-fly generation of file, sorry for any misunderstanding.

PS2: It seems I get an overhead of downloaded file (8085 bytes of original and 13000+ of downloaded) and I can't figure it out where this overhead is come in.

Comment: I dont know how you are using the front, but in a project I had this type of error because the download started before the finish of writing the file on the server.

Comment: He used a flush so I think the writing is done.

Comment: Is the call to `SaveAs` necessary since you're not actually trying to write to disk? Also the correct MIME content type for xlsx is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: @Adrian no, it is absolutly unnecessary, I used it to get valid file to check it worked. Thank you for the correct MIME.

Comment: Can you write the bytes to a file to compare it to original file? And in case you didn't realize, `ServeContent` serves a file **from memory**.

Comment: @leafbebop 
    ...
    fileSize := strconv.Itoa(len(fileContents))

    ff, _ := os.Create("/tmp/222.xlsx")
    ff.Write(fileContents)
    defer ff.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xlsx")
    ...

This code gives me two working files same size.

ServeContent returns corrupted file too.

Comment: And did the corrupted file have anything similar to the original one? Try use a hex dump to analyse what it contains.

Comment: The code `t := bytes.NewReader(b.Bytes()); io.Copy(w, t)` can be simplified to `w.Write(b.Bytes())`.

Comment: Almost four years later, I stumbled across the same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: I had the same problem using "Advanced Rest Client" (a chrome extension for sending requests). try using chrome itself (for GET request), postman and other tools.

Answer (score 2):

For serving a reader, you should consider `http.ServeContent`. It will handle the header, content range and so on for you.
Change the line with`io.Copy` with `http.ServeContent(w,r,"testfile.xlsx",time.Now(),t)` and it shall work.
Documents: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent

Comment: I don't want to serve file from disk. I want to generate file on the fly and send it to client. I use `SaveAs` function just to make sure that file is valid.

Comment: It indeed serve file from memory as it takes a readseeker. @therox

Answer (score 1):

i use *File.write api and it works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2"
)

func main() {

    s := http.Server{
        Addr: ":8012",
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/foo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        f := excelize.NewFile()
        // Set value of a cell.
        f.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "B2", 100)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.xlsx")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
        f.Write(w)
    })

    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```